# Why do I have to hold down a cell in my tableview to open it?

Tags: swift, tableview

It seems like with a few apps that I've made and launched to my IPhone, I have to hold down on a table view cell to before any functionally I programmed happens. Can anyone tell me why, and how to fix it?

here is an example

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let message = messages[indexPath.row]
    let chatPartnerId: String?
    if message.fromId == FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid{
        chatPartnerId = message.toId
    }else{
        chatPartnerId = message.fromId
    }

    let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").child(chatPartnerId!)
    ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        guard let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String:AnyObject] else{
            return
        }
        let user = User()
        user.uid = chatPartnerId
        user.setValuesForKeys(dictionary)
        chosenUser = user
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "chatLog1", sender: nil)
    })



}
```

Comment: Can you give an example of the code that triggers one of these actions and where you're executing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using the didSelectRowAt:indexPath method you could use the didHighlightRowAt:indexPath method like this:

```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didHighlightRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "chatLog1", sender: nil)
    }
```